# Jquery which event is better than this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page in html (parent page) that have inside an iframe. When you navigate inside iframe (reload iframe's page or click on link) the parent page remains in its previous position. So i used scrollTop to bring back at the top the page.

All works fine but jquery do it only when the iframe is completely loaded (image inluded..) so this is not well...

How can i scrollTop (PARENT PAGE) before the iframe's page is completely loaded?

Parent page body code:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').load(function(){
         $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});</script>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="1000" id="iframe" src="http://mysite.com" width="800"></iframe>
```

Thanx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

         $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps?

```
$('iframe').ready(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: The documentation says it does not matter what you pass to `.ready` because it will always use the current document.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I'm reading you correctly:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(){
 $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
 $('#iframe1').attr('src', 'http://some-other-url');
 window.frames["iframe1"].location.reload();
});
```

Comment: No..it doesn't...the situation is this: that's the parent page http://foicam.blogspot.com/p/guarda-le-webcam.html try to scroll down the page and then clik on the bottom image "Prova 5 Mpixel". you will see that the new iframe page will be loaded when the parent page is still down and it will return up only when browser finish the iframe new page loading...(i'm using my code) thanx for help!

Comment: What i'm saying is do the load of prova 5 Mpixel AFTER you do the scrollTo but do that load entirely via javascript. Thus the page moves before you load the iframe

Comment: OK so must be correct! Plese can you help me to modify the code to do this? I discovered the existence of this language this afternoon!!!